# How to use built-in spreadsheet functions using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just start using a spreadsheet programming with GAS but can't find the answer to my trivial question.

I want to obtain the highest number in a column in a spreadsheet.
Opening the spreadsheet and obtaining a range is not a problem, but I don't know how to use built-in spreadsheet functions like MAX()

```
   var ss = openSpreadsheetByName(MyName);
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var range = sheet.range(1, 1, lastRow, 1);
```

Now I would like to use  `var maxId = range.max();` or `var maxId = max(range);`
In general I would like to use built-in spreadsheet functions. But don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is **not** possible. This is one of the oldest requests for Apps Script, see [issue 26 - Enable scripts to use standard spreadsheet functions](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=26).

Comment: As calling built-in spreadsheet functions is one of the important feautures of VBA, the conclusion can only be that Google doesn't care about migration from Excel and/or their users. It makes you think about if it is wise using Google at all !

Comment: Yeah, that's sad indeed.